# How can I use a Java ConcurrentNavigableMap with comparator instead of a TreeMap?

Tags: java, sorting

I need build Queue that will stay allways sorted by its keys . 
the TreeMap seams to be great for it like in this example :
http://www.javaexamples4u.com/2009/03/treemap-comparator.html
but the big problem is that its not thread safe , then i found ConcurrentNavigableMap
great , but how do i use the comparator the same way as with the TreeMap? i didn't found any example for it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are actually looking for a [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).  If you need a thread-safe version of it, you can use a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html).

A priority queue is a queue where you can retrieve items ordered by "importance."  In the case of Java, you can use a Comparator or the items' natural order (if they implement Comparable).

If you really need to use a ConcurrentNavigableMap, you will need to use an implementation of it such as [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).  Just allocate an instance of ConcurrentSkipListMap and pass it the comparator you want to use.

```
new ConcurrentSkipListMap<MyKeyType, MyValueType>(new MyKeyComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentNavigableMap is just the interface. You need to use a concrete class implementing it, which in the standard collections library is **ConcurrentSkipListMap**.

You should basically be able to use ConcurrentSkipListMap as a drop-in replacement for TreeMap, including using the comparator. Operations will generally have similar performance characteristics (O(log n)), but as I understand the size() operation of ConcurrentSkipListMap requires traversal of the skip list rather than simply reading a variable, so just be slightly careful if you call this frequently on a large map.